# How to turn on Spring's component-scan debugging info?

Tags: debugging, spring-mvc, logging

I am trying to find out the number of database tables the application I am maintaining, uses. I have this in my appContext.xml

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo, com.bar" use-default-filters="false">
 <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
 <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component" />
 <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
 </context:component-scan>
         ....
 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.foo.abc, com.bar.def" />
```

There are other sub projects associated with this project where `@Entity` and `@Repository` have liberally been used. I am thinking if I am just able to turn on Spring's debugging somehow, which will list all classnames as and when it scans them based on the base package, I should be able to find all jpa repositories. How can I turn on springs debugging to spit out this information ?

This is what I have in my log4j.properties :

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, file
log4j.category.org.hibernate=debug, hb
log4j.category.org.springframework=debug, spring
```

Answer (score 24):

It's a bit old topic but I found solution that worked for me (Spring 4.1.7):

```
<logger name="org.springframework.core.io.support" level="debug"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.context.annotation" level="debug"/>
```

Comment: By default (web-starter) Spring uses Logback so this should be put in a logback.xml file.

Comment: malformed xml, where should this go?

Answer (score 4):

The class that handles registering the repositories is `org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate`. You need to either set your `rootLogger` level to debug or configure log4j to have a child logger for `org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate` or any of its parents with log level DEBUG.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the properties mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873057/1587329) in the application.properties (or e.g. application-development.properties)

```
logging.level.org.springframework.core.io.support=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.context.annotation=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debug level logging for:

1. `org.springframework.context.annotation` for component scan report:

Example:

```
2021-05-01 02:58:51.553 [Test worker] [DEBUG] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: file [/absolute/path/to/TestController.class]
```

2. `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging` for auto configuration report.

Example:

```
ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)
```