# Spring Boot: Configuration Class is simply ignored and not loaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following `@Configuration` class on the classpath of a few of my `@SpringBootApplication`s:

```
@Configuration
@Import({MainConfig.class, RestConfig.class})
public class ApiConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Client client() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return service.create(Client.class);
    }

}
```

I have two services that use this config (with differently named `Client` classes).

Service 1 starts correctly and loads this config. I can see during start up that a bean of type `ApiConfig` was eagerly initialized.

Service 2 starts incorrectly: the above configuration class is simply ignored and not initialized.

The services are started in separate JVMs.

Ther services have nearly identical, very small `application.properties` files:

```
spring.application.name=xxx-api
server.port=0
eureka.name=xxx.api
# Only for reading properties from a central location
context.initializer.classes=com.package.contextClass
```

I'm not even sure what kind of additional information I could write into the question. I have been going through logs for a couple of hours now and see no discernible difference, simply that it plainly ignores my `@Configuration` class.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: How is this configuration class supposed to get loaded? You didn't show your Spring Boot bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry, it is supposed to get loaded using `@SpringBootApplication`, i.e. using `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: In both cases is the @Configuration class in the same package as your Springboot application class?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation (or, more precisely the inferred `@ComponentScan` annotation) by default only scans the classpath next to and below the annotated class.

So, your configuration class must be placed next to or in a sub package of you Application class.

Comment: wow.. thanks. It amazing how much confusion a misplaced package can be. I thought I was going crazy but it was just that my @Configuration class was not being run because it was not  next to or in a sub package of my Application class

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599238/how-to-turn-on-springs-component-scan-debugging-info for showing component scan debug messages.