# Using Spring Cloud Stream to produce Avro Messages using the Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to Spring Cloud Stream and trying to produce Avro messages based on the Confluent Schema Registry.

I can get the very basic example, https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/ working, but when I try to extend it further to use Avro, I am getting exceptions.

As a generic test environment, I am running the Docker image:
https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev/

The test project was generated and slightly modified using Spring Initializr:
https://start.spring.io/

**The pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.demo.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>kafka-demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    <project-avro.version>7.0.0-SNAPSHOT</project-avro.version>
    <apache.avro.version>1.8.2</apache.avro.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-schema</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>${apache.avro.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>project.foundation</groupId>
      <artifactId>maritz-avro</artifactId>
      <version>${project-avro.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**I have published the following schema to the registry:**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "RoutingSlipMsg",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "projectNumber",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "clientName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "programTheme",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "databaseName",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "actionType",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Original Test application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      schema:
        avro:
          dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled: true
      bindings:
        output:
          binder: kafka
          destination: routing_slip_dev
#          contentType: application/avro
#          contentType: application/*+avro
          contentType: application/com.project.RoutingSlipMsg.v1+avro
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://192.168.99.100:8081
      kafka:
        binder:
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          defaultZkPort: 2181
          zkNodes: 192.168.99.100
          brokers: 192.168.99.100
```

**Test application.yml edits:**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      schema:
        avro:
          dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled: true
      bindings:
        output:
          binder: kafka
          destination: routing_slip_dev
#          contentType: application/*+avro
#          contentType: application/avro
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://192.168.99.100:8081
      kafka:
        binder:
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          defaultZkPort: 2181
          zkNodes: 192.168.99.100
          brokers: 192.168.99.100
```

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
public class DemoConfiguration {


  @Bean
  public ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient() {
    ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient registry = new ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient();
    registry.setEndpoint("http://192.168.99.100:8081");
    return registry;
  }

}
```

The auto topic creation seems to be working properly.  I can change the *destination:* value to something else each time and a new topic will be created.

**Test**

```
package com.project.kafka.kafkademo;

import com.project.avro.RoutingSlipMsg;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class KafkaDemoApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private KafkaRoutingSlipSender kafkaRoutingSlipSender;

  @Test
  public void testSend() throws Exception {

    RoutingSlipMsg routingSlip = new RoutingSlipMsg();
    routingSlip.setActionType("FAKE_ACTION");
    routingSlip.setClientName("TEST_CLIENT");
    routingSlip.setDatabaseName("NONE");
    routingSlip.setProgramTheme("THEME");
    routingSlip.setProjectNumber("ABC123");

    kafkaRoutingSlipSender.send(routingSlip);
  }
}
```

**BootApplication class*

```
package com.project.kafka.kafkademo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaDemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(KafkaDemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

**Original Sender class**

```
package com.project.kafka.kafkademo;

import com.project.avro.RoutingSlipMsg;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.client.EnableSchemaRegistryClient;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class KafkaRoutingSlipSender {


  @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT)
  public MessageSource<RoutingSlipMsg> send(RoutingSlipMsg data) {
    System.out.println("**** Hello World ****");
    return () -> {
      return new GenericMessage<>(data);
    };
  }
}
```

**Sender Class Edits:**

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class KafkaRoutingSlipSender {

  @Autowired
  private Source source;

  public void send(RoutingSlipMsg data) {
    System.out.println("**** Hello World ****");
    source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(data).build());
  }
}
```

**Original Stacktrace / Exception due to inappropriate use of `@InboundChannelAdapter`**

```
2017-07-06 12:20:48.645 ERROR 69011 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to invoke method; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MethodInvokingMessageSource.doReceive(MethodInvokingMessageSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:201)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MethodInvokingMessageSource.doReceive(MethodInvokingMessageSource.java:116)
    ... 20 more
```

I have reviewed several different posts on here, but nothing seems to be helping.
What might I be missing?

**Update 1:**
I have made updates to the `KafkaRoutingSlipSender` class and the `application.yml` as shown above.  With the `contentType` removed, these changes will publish a message like:

```
ÿcontentType?"application/x-java-object;type=com.maritz.avro.RoutingSlipMsg"FAKE_ACTIOÎTEST_CLIENÔNONÅTHEMÅABC12³
```

to the topic.

However, when I set the `contentType` to `application/*+avro`, the `@Autowired Source` appears to be casuing a `NullPointerException`.

**New Stacktrace / Exception:**

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'output'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"projectNumber": "ABC123", "clientName": "TEST_CLIENT", "programTheme": "THEME", "databaseName": "NONE", "actionType": "FAKE_ACTION"}, headers={id=9a9ebc45-9431-8de5-1cb0-40d191082599, timestamp=1499438830456}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:449)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at com.maritz.kafka.kafkademo.KafkaRoutingSlipSender.send(KafkaRoutingSlipSender.java:22)
    at com.maritz.kafka.kafkademo.KafkaDemoApplicationTests.testSend(KafkaDemoApplicationTests.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.client.DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.register(DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.resolveSchemaForWriting(AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AbstractAvroMessageConverter.convertToInternal(AbstractAvroMessageConverter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$ContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:253)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
    ... 31 more
```

**Update 2 (07-10-2017):**
I have fixed the `null` Source issue, thanks to this information:

[Spring Boot: Configuration Class is simply ignored and not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003355/spring-boot-configuration-class-is-simply-ignored-and-not-loaded)

The `ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient` is now being used.  I can step into the code when debugging, but it doesn't find the schema.

**ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient.register(String subject, String format, String schema)**

```
ResponseEntity<Map> response = this.template.exchange(this.endpoint + path, HttpMethod.POST, request, Map.class, new Object[0]);
```

**New Stacktrace / Exception (07-10-2017):**

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'output'; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"projectNumber": "ABC123", "clientName": "TEST_CLIENT", "programTheme": "THEME", "databaseName": "NONE", "actionType": "FAKE_ACTION"}, headers={id=73365130-a91b-ba9c-aaf0-77cfaa26f73d, timestamp=1499700409997}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:449)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at com.maritz.kafka.kafkademo.KafkaRoutingSlipSender.send(KafkaRoutingSlipSender.java:29)
    at com.maritz.kafka.kafkademo.KafkaDemoApplicationTests.testSend(KafkaDemoApplicationTests.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.client.ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient.register(ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.resolveSchemaForWriting(AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AbstractAvroMessageConverter.convertToInternal(AbstractAvroMessageConverter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$ContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:253)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
    ... 31 more
```

Is the `register()` supposed to be creating a new schema if that one doesn't exist, or is the 404 appropriate behavior?  Quite confused.

Comment: How does it work if you add `@Bean` alongside with the `@InboundChannelAdapter` ?

Comment: Although your design is wrong. The `@InboundChannelAdapter` is an entry point and can't be called from the target code. You should consider to use `@MessagingGateway` instead, if you are not familiar with `@ServiceActivator` and `MessageChannel` concepts.

Comment: Please note that you should use `application/*+avro` as the contentType. It acts as a trigger to enable Schema Resolution. Once the schemaClient sees that it then goes on Schema Resolution processe, take a look on how it actually works: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_schema_registration_and_resolution

Comment: @ViniciusCarvalho please see the edits I have made to the original post with the results of setting the `contentType` vs not.

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

An `@InboundChannelAdapter` method cannot have any parameters...

```
/**
 * Indicates that a method is capable of producing a {@link org.springframework.messaging.Message}
 * or {@link org.springframework.messaging.Message} {@code payload}.
 * <p>
 * A method annotated with {@code @InboundChannelAdapter} can't accept any parameters.
 * <p>    
 * Return values from the annotated method may be of any type. If the return
 * value is not a {@link org.springframework.messaging.Message}, a {@link org.springframework.messaging.Message}
 * will be created with that object as its {@code payload}.

...
```

It is polled for a message, or message payload.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell for pointing out what should have been obvious.
Would a proper use case for `@InboudChannelAdapter` be something like a using it with a scheduled task? 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: It's similar, but it sends a message to `MessageChannel`; the message payload is the returned result. Scheduled tasks can't return a value and can only have a `void` return type.

Answer (score 3):

So what you see as `application/x-java-object;type=com.maritz.avro.RoutingSlipMsg` is because the default contentType for java objects is to serialize using Kryo, and that's what it set as contentType.

Since you want to use Confluent Schema Registry, that is not the default one, you need to setup a ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient bean, check it here how to enable it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_schema_registry_client

You now have a DefaultSchemaRegistryClient and it's probably having issues since the REST interface between the default server and confluent are not the same.

Comment: I can't find any mention of how to configure to use the Confluent Registry.

Spring Cloud Stream provides out of the box implementations for interacting with its own schema server, as well as for interacting with the Confluent Schema Registry.

A client for the Spring Cloud Stream schema registry can be configured using the `@EnableSchemaRegistryClient`

I only see those mentions of how to configure the Spring Registry.

Comment: Oops, I guess we need to fix those docs then. Just provide a Bean of type `org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.client.ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient` and it will be used instead. You can set the endpoint if your server is not running on localhost:8081. There's also a `CachingRegistryClient` that can delegate to confluent's one, you will need to `@EnableCaching` to get it working though

Comment: I have added a Configration class (see addition to original posting), but still getting a `null` Source.

Comment: Should the values in the `application.yml` be flowing through to set the `schemaRegistryClient.endpoint` as well?

Comment: Fixed the `null` Source problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003355/spring-boot-configuration-class-is-simply-ignored-and-not-loaded

Comment: @ViniciusCarvalhodo do you have an idea of when the docs will be updated?

Answer (score 1):

We are working on the docs, should be ready soon. In the meantime just expose this on your application:

```
@Bean
public SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient(@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}") String endpoint){
    ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient client = new ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient();
    client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    return client;
}
```

Comment: I've added this bean and traced the code until it does the HTTP request, but it's still fialing for me and I'm guessing it's because the client I'm using is not working with confluent 3.3.0 API, as I'm getting this error:

`POST request for "http://localhost:8081/subjects/order" resulted in 404 (Not Found); invoking error handler`

I'm missing the `versions` segment in that path according to this README https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry#quickstart

Comment: Update to latest SCSt 1.3, it seems that your app is pulling 1.2 from Dalston