# Spring Boot and OAuth2 server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a simple OAuth2 server with Spring Boot.
In the first step I added in the main class the annotation @EnableAuthorizationServer

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class PocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PocApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and I use the "application.yml" file to configure all the OAuth2 elements.

```
server:
  port: 8282
spring:
  security:
    user: 
      name: root
      password: root
      roles: ADMIN,USER
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: mobile 
      client-secret: pin
      access-token-validity-seconds: 3600
      authorized-grant-types: client_credential,password
      scope: READ, WRITE
    authorization:
      check-token-access: permitAll
```

With this configuration everything works fine. 
In the second step I tried to switch the configuration from yml file to java class.
These are the classes that I created

```
@Configuration
public class AuthServerConfigurations extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer client) throws Exception {
        client.inMemory().withClient("mobile").secret(passwordEncoder.encode("pin")).scopes("READ", "WRITE").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "client_credential");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoint) throws Exception {
        endpoint.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class UserConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder=PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();


    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("root").password(passwordEncoder.encode("root")).roles("USER","ADMIN");
    }
}
```

With this configuration the app doesn't work.
When I run the project via maven I see that Spring generate a new "client-id" and "client-secret" instead to use "mobile" and "pin"

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id = 27234511-14a5-4b94-9cd3-ffc77c5189f3
security.oauth2.client.client-secret = 5895bf76-6b30-4160-9f13-1cbad7b986e5
```

this is the log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.0)

2022-02-02 09:55:12.291  INFO 113288 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8282 (http)
2022-02-02 09:55:12.413  INFO 113288 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-02 09:55:12.414  INFO 113288 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2022-02-02 09:55:12.711  INFO 113288 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-02 09:55:12.712  INFO 113288 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5978 ms
2022-02-02 09:55:13.407  INFO 113288 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :

Using generated security password: 940524c4-8efa-4d7d-826b-864ff4b48392

2022-02-02 09:55:13.826  INFO 113288 --- [           main] a.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration : Initialized OAuth2 Client

security.oauth2.client.client-id = 27234511-14a5-4b94-9cd3-ffc77c5189f3
security.oauth2.client.client-secret = 5895bf76-6b30-4160-9f13-1cbad7b986e5


2022-02-02 09:55:15.130  INFO 113288 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Or [Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']] with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@41bfa9e9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@13ed066e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@68ef01a5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5ae15, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@1bbddada, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@590765c4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@64b018f3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@68b7d0ef, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7126e26, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4872669f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@59c500f7]
2022-02-02 09:55:15.301  INFO 113288 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8282 (http) with context path ''
```

Why the java class configuration  doesn't work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem is at this link

[Spring Boot: Configuration Class is simply ignored and not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003355/spring-boot-configuration-class-is-simply-ignored-and-not-loaded)

My config files were in a different package so I added the

> @ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.config.package")

in the main class after

> @SpringBootApplication

and it works.