# Spring dependency injection not working with inheritance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, dao

I have a generic base dao class in which I implemented some generic methods for all daos.

```
<bean id="baseDAO" class="com.db.dao.BaseDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDAO" class="com.db.dao.UserDao"></bean>

<bean id="notesDAO" class="com.db.dao.NotesDao"></bean>
```

Initially, I was using the dependency injection to inject `sessionFactory` to every single dao, but later on I had implemented a base dao and had every other daos to extend this base dao.

However, after the change, whenever I call `getSessionFactory()` from one of the daos, I get `null` as return. The change makes sense to me but I cannot seem to figure out why it would return `null` since I've had the `factorySession` injected in the base.

**BaseDao**

```
public class BaseDao<T> {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
       this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    ...
}
```

**UserDao**

```
public class UserDao extends BaseDao<User> {

    public User read(String userName) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please post some code. BaseDAO and a "child" DAO would be nice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599238/how-to-turn-on-springs-component-scan-debugging-info This will tell you if the scanning is picking up what you think it should be picking up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way i see it is that you forgot to add `parent` attribute on the children:

```
<bean id="baseDAO" class="com.db.dao.BaseDao" abstract="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDAO" class="com.db.dao.UserDao" parent="baseDAO"></bean>

<bean id="notesDAO" class="com.db.dao.NotesDao" parent="baseDAO"></bean>
```

I think its also a good idea if you mark the BaseDAO as `abstract`.

Comment: people always overlook simple things. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Welcome. Glad i could help