# Which packages are considered in the component scan by Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that uses marker interfaces to define the packages that should be used for component scanning:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ModelComponents.class, WebComponents.class, ServiceComponents.class})
```

In a package under `ModelComponents` there is an interface defined that is used as a service and has it's implementation in `ServiceComponents`, but somehow does not get picked up.

Using debug level debug on the spring package (VM option: `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`) I can see that all the spring beans from the first two components are picked up, but none from the third one.

Enabling this debug information gives more output than restricting to a more specific package like described in [How to turn on Spring's component-scan debugging info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599238/how-to-turn-on-springs-component-scan-debugging-info), but all I get out of this is log output like:

```
DEBUG | .c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner |                        | Identified candidate component class: file [...\ActivityLogService.class]
DEBUG | .c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner |                        | Identified candidate component class: file [...TopayMwApplicationProperties.class]
DEBUG | .c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner |                        | Identified candidate component class: file [...ChallengeService.class]
```

This tells me all about the beans that were found, but it does not give any hint about the others: where they not found because the package was ignored, or did spring look at the base package and find no beans?

Is there a way to get at the information which package is considered for the component scan or which marker interface is used?

How would this be recognizable in the log?

Comment: @M.Deinum that one has been closed and is now deleted, as it lacked some details that made it clear it is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599238/how-to-turn-on-springs-component-scan-debugging-info

Answer (score 0):

Here, Spring will look for the components under the packages of those classes you specified. I mean Spring will search the components under the package of ModelComponents.class, the package of WebComponents.class, and the package of ServiceComponents.class. Therefore

1. if your implementation class is not under one of these packages then it'll be ignored.
2. if your implementation class is not annotated as a Spring component, then it'll be ignored

Comment: I am aware of this and my services are annotated with `Service` and are on in the same package (or subpackage) of the marker interface.

Comment: why not using basePackages instead of basePackageClasses?

Comment: Because using types is refactor safe: if you rename the package you can forget to update the string in basePackages, though some IDE support there a bit.

Comment: I see. Why don't you just let Spring locate them automatically by not defining any packages or classes in your @ComponentScan annotation. Then it'll recognize every component under the same package of your config class and subpackages automatically.

Comment: Not all beans are in a subpackage of the application class and I need to be able to be selective.

Comment: So how do you understand that the components in your service packages are not picked up? Your project does not compile? I see in the debug log that there are some classes with a Service suffix such as ActivityLogService. This class is not under the service packages?

Answer (score 0):

Aparently this information cannot be retrieved through the log. The class `org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser` does resolve the `basePackageClasses` array from the annotation into an array of packages in the `parse` method.

Debugging into the issue shows that I go in with 3 marker interface classes but come out with only 2 packages.

As the example from the question is not the real life example it does not show the full truth, which causes it: There are two marker interface with the same name but one is in the subpackage of the other and the one from the subpackage was imported and used twice in the `basePackageClasses`.

As a consequence the beans one package above are not in a package that is scanned.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've submitted looks correct, even though as mentioned by other commenters this might be your classes placement issues.
The code I use for setting packages to scan is this:

```
scanBasePackages = {"ru.company.package", "ru.company.anotherpackage"}
```

Even though its less safe due to possible typos it sets the package explicitly and it might give you more info on the error.